# How come this both loop runs equally fast when compiled with -O3, but not when compiled with -O2?

Tags: c++, optimization

In below program I expect test1 to run slower because of the dependent instructions. A test run with -O2 seemed to confirm this. But then I tried with -O3 and now the timings are more or less equal. How can this be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>

volatile int x = 0; // used for preventing certain optimizations


enum { size = 60 * 1000 * 1000 };
std::vector<unsigned> a(size + x); // `size + x` makes the vector size unknown by compiler 
std::vector<unsigned> b(size + x);


void test1()
{
    for (auto i = 1u; i != size; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = a[i] + a[i-1]; // data dependency hinders pipelining(?)
    }
}


void test2()
{
    for (auto i = 0u; i != size; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = a[i] + b[i]; // no data dependencies
    }
}


template<typename F>
int64_t benchmark(F&& f)
{
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto elapsed_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_time);
    return elapsed_ms.count();
}


int main(int argc, char**)
{   
    // make sure the optimizer cannot make any assumptions
    // about the contents of the vectors:
    for (auto& el : a) el = x;
    for (auto& el : b) el = x;

    test1(); // warmup
    std::cout << "test1: " << benchmark(&test1) << '\n';

    test2(); // warmup        
    std::cout << "\ntest2: " << benchmark(&test2) << '\n';

    return a[x] * x; // prevent optimization and exit with code 0
}
```

I get these results:

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 main.cpp && ./a.out
test1: 115
test2: 48

g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp && ./a.out
test1: 29
test2: 38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `-O3` gcc effectively eliminates the data dependency, by storing the value of `a[i]` in a register and reusing it on the next iteration instead of loading `a[i-1]`.

The result is more or less equivalent to:

```
void test1()
{
    auto x = a[0];
    auto end = a.begin() + size;
    for (auto it = next(a.begin()); it != end; ++it)
    {
        auto y = *it; // Load
        x = y + x;
        *it = x; // Store
    }
}
```

Which compiled in `-O2` yield the exact same assembly as your code compiled in `-O3`.

The second loop in your question is unrolled in `-O3`, hence the speedup. The two optimizations applied seem to be unrelated to me, the first case is faster simply because gcc removed a load instruction, the second because it is unrolled.

In both cases I don't think that the optimizer did anything in particular to improve the cache behavior, both memory access patterns are easy predictable by the cpu.

Comment: I see how the register allocation could improve the situation by reducing memory accesses. But there still seems to be a dependency: updating the register must precede the write to memory. Is this really better "pipelinable"?

Comment: @StackedCrooked Yes but the write can be reordered after the load on the next iteration (x86 can move stores after loads). So I think that here the cpu  will just load a cache-line, do the math, then update that cache line. Even if the loop are pipelined, there's so few instructions that fetching the data is the bottleneck anyway, so the second loop is going to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizers are very sophisticated pieces of software and not always predictable.

With g++ 5.2.0 and -O2 `test1` and `test2` gets compiled to similar machine code:

```
  ;;;; test1 inner loop
  400c28:   8b 50 fc                mov    -0x4(%rax),%edx
  400c2b:   01 10                   add    %edx,(%rax)
  400c2d:   48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
  400c31:   48 39 c1                cmp    %rax,%rcx
  400c34:   75 f2                   jne    400c28 <_Z5test1v+0x18>

  ;;;; test2 inner loop
  400c50:   8b 0c 06                mov    (%rsi,%rax,1),%ecx
  400c53:   01 0c 02                add    %ecx,(%rdx,%rax,1)
  400c56:   48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
  400c5a:   48 3d 00 1c 4e 0e       cmp    $0xe4e1c00,%rax
  400c60:   75 ee                   jne    400c50 <_Z5test2v+0x10>
```

however with `-O3` test1 remains more or less similar

```
  ;;;; test1 inner loop
  400d88:   03 10                   add    (%rax),%edx
  400d8a:   48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
  400d8e:   89 50 fc                mov    %edx,-0x4(%rax)
  400d91:   48 39 c1                cmp    %rax,%rcx
  400d94:   75 f2                   jne    400d88 <_Z5test1v+0x18>
```

while `test2` explodes to what it seems an unrolled version using `xmm` registers and generates completely different machine code. The inner loop becomes

```
  ;;;; test2 inner loop (after a lot of preprocessing)
  400e30:   f3 41 0f 6f 04 00       movdqu (%r8,%rax,1),%xmm0
  400e36:   83 c1 01                add    $0x1,%ecx
  400e39:   66 0f fe 04 07          paddd  (%rdi,%rax,1),%xmm0
  400e3e:   0f 29 04 07             movaps %xmm0,(%rdi,%rax,1)
  400e42:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
  400e46:   44 39 c9                cmp    %r9d,%ecx
  400e49:   72 e5                   jb     400e30 <_Z5test2v+0x90>
```

and works doing multiple additions for each iteration.

If you want to test specific processor behavior probably writing directly in a assembler is a better idea as C++ compilers may do some heavy rewriting of what your original source code is doing.

Comment: Tip: _"probably writing directly in a assembler"_ You surely meant to say _assembly_, as the _assembler_ is what compiles an assembly source code to object code.

Comment: @black: I never liked the "assembly" form and I prefer to use "assembler language". Apparently even wikipedia agrees it's a viable option...